# How to fire window.scrollY only one time

Tags: javascript, function, scroll, addeventlistener

I am trying to fire window.scrollY only one time, currently my below code works fine but fire multiple times.

When i run this code it fired multiple times i want to stop this, only window scroll should fire only one time when we scroll the browser.

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    window.scrollY > 30 && fetch("https://ip2c.org/self").then((function(t) {
        t.text().then((function(t) {
            t.includes("IND") && (document.getElementById("IN").style.display = "flex")
        }))
    }))
});
```

But when i try to run this code to fire window scroll only one time with help of true/false variable value but it doesn't work check below what i have tried.

```
var fired = false;
window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    window.scrollY > 30 && fired === false && fetch("https://ip2c.org/self").then((function(t) {
        t.text().then((function(t) {
            t.includes("IND") && (document.getElementById("IN").style.display = "flex")
        }))
    }))
}, true)
```

Any kind of help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Is this possible to make window.scrollY fire only onetime.

Comment: Dear, i want to fire window scroll only one time but above code fired multiple times, is there any advice how to stop this?

Comment: You're never setting `fired` to `true` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not setting the variable `fired` to true; besides that,
the best option would be to use the `removeEventListener(eventName, fn)`:

```js
const myScrollFetch = () => {

  if (window.scrollY <= 30) return; // Do nothing
  
  // Stop listening to scroll event
  window.removeEventListener("scroll", myScrollFetch);
  
  window.scrollY > 30 && fetch("https://ip2c.org/self").then((function(t) {
    t.text().then((function(t) {
      t.includes("IND") && (document.getElementById("IN").style.display = "flex")
    }));
  }));
}

// Listen to scroll event
window.addEventListener("scroll", myScrollFetch);
```

Comment: Sorry i test the code it doesn't work, it doesn't fetch the url to make display flex in style attribute.

Comment: This code now works after spending my two hours, just remove the `&& fired === false ` from your above solution, then i will mark your question as solved.

Comment: @BloggerTemplates wooops I forgot to get rid of that variable (as I was ironically trying to explain in the above paragraphs :) ). **Fixed.**